# How to bind a POCO object to a WPF GUI?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, datacontext

I have three pictures in a simple WPF application. A car, a plane and a train.

When I click on either of them, I load an appropriate "transportation" object that has the name of the transportation, a picture file path, and other string properties. A simple POCO object.

How do I declare a *template* of sorts, in XAML, so I can then apply that POCO object as it's data source and put property X inside of element Foo?

Here is my simple XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>Car</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>Slow</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>4 Wheels</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

So the properties here would be template holders for the POCO I provide.

How do I provide this data context?

Answer (score 5):

```
<StackPanel x:Name="transportPanel">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Speed}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Components}" />
</StackPanel>
```

And in code, you set the data context:

```
transportPanel.DataContext = myCarObject;
```

WPF can only bind to *properties*, not to *fields*, so keep that in mind when designing your POCOs.

Comment: Another relates question, sometimes (almost always) XAML controls are nested. Does the "context" drill down into the very inner controls?

Comment: @SergioTapia: Yes. In fact, it's common practice to set just the DataContext of the Window to some POCO object (called the ViewModel) and then go deeper into the object tree by just setting `DataContext="{Binding SomePropertyOfTheViewModelReturningAnotherPoco}"` on some inner control.